# Ignore files in Eclipse without adding them to .cvsignore

Tags: eclipse, version-control, synchronization, cvs, ignore

Is it somehow possible to permanently ignore files and folders when synchronizing in Eclipse *without* adding them to the `.cvsignore` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The other ignore mechanism you can find in **Preferences -> Team -> Ignored Resources**.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It seams like this mechanism is for adding files to `.cvsignore`.